# What is second parameter in nodejs post method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my code I have code written like this

```
 router.post('/', publicShare, function(req, res, next) {
```

I check in [documents](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) but not found why second param `publicShare` is here?

`publicShare` is looks like

```
var publicShare = function(req, res, next) {
    if (condition1) {
        if (condition2) {
            res.status(400).send({success:false});
        } else {
            next();       
        }
    } else {
        if (condition3) {
            res.status(401).send({success:false});
        } else
            next();
    }
};
```

Please help me to understand.

Comment: It's [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), per [the API documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.METHOD).

Comment: Well precisely its express middle ware function

Comment: Thanks a lot @jonrsharpe and Shubh I am new in node js

Comment: Now I read the text I was searching is `A series of middleware functions (separated by commas).`

Comment: @ShubhDixit : Please help me to ignore that second middleware what I do ? just writing `next();` at very first line of `publicShare` is not working ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check [route handlers](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-handlers) which accepts array of callbacks which just behaves like a middleware. Example from the docs:

```
app.get('/example/d', [cb0, cb1], function (req, res, next) {
```

So, in your case `publicShare` can be array of callbacks or just a callback which signature is just a callback accepting `req`, `res`, and `next` as parameter. So, you can also use like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){}, function(req, res, next){}, ...
```

And for easier, you would use an array of callbacks:

```
app.get('/',[cb1, cb2, cb3])
```

Where cb1, cb2, and cb3 are the callbacks with request, response and next parameters. It allows you to run one by one. cb1 -> do log 1, then cb2 -> do log 2, cb3 -> do log 3 and so on.

**I would simplify this with an example:**

You would request for water.

1) cb1: Purchase a jar of water.

2) cb2: Add few water drops in the bucket or jar.

3) cb3: Boil it.

Then, it's your turn. Drink!

Answer (score 3):

`publicShare` method in your route is a express middleware function .According to the docs

> Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request
>   object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware
>   function in the application’s request-response cycle

A middleware checks for certain condition or criteria to be applied on your request and response object ,if the criteria fulfills then the next operation is done ,which is either

> 1-End the request response cycle
>
> 2-Call the next middleware function in the stack.

You can refer the docs for more information -https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: Please help me to ignore that second middleware what I do ? just writing `next();` at very first line of `publicShare` is not working ?

Comment: @ctrlf5 you can either remove it ,or directly call next() in it remove every other thing like `var publicShare = function(req, res, next) {
   next();
};`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.METHOD), you can add multiple middleware functions separated by commas. The 'publicShare' variable must be a middleware function.

Comment: Please help me to ignore that second middleware what I do ?

Comment: you could just remove it: 'router.post('/', function(req, res, next) { //yourcode}