# What is the middleware and app.use in expess?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Just want to say at the beginning. I'm really sorry if you will consider this as a duplicate but I'd like to ask you what is the middleware. I know stackoverflow has some similar questions but I'd be glad if you could answer this one. Also what is the .use ? Where do we use it? Thank you very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54608159/7849549 ,Have a look at following answer.hope it helps and we use`middlewares` using `app.use()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware is a term that refers to request handlers that "pre-process" an incoming request.  A given middleware will typically run on lots of incoming requests.  Usually, it doesn't send the final response, it just does some setup or pre-processing on the request and then passes the request on to its eventual handler.  There are thousands on things that people find to do with middleware.

The general idea is that it's easier to put middleware in one place and configure it to apply to lots of requests rather than have to add it to every single request handler that its supposed to apply to.

I'll offer a few examples:

1. Check to see if the requester is authenticated/loggedin on the site.  If not, then redirect to the login page.  If so, then pass the request through to the actual page request handler.
2. Log usage or performance statistics.
3. Pre-parse query parameters so they're already parsed for the request handler
4. Pre-parse post bodies so they're already parsed for the request handler
5. Preset desired cross origin headers for the response

Hopefully, you can see the general idea that middleware is often used as pre-setup work that can be done in one place rather than having to be added to every single request handler.

Keep in mind that middleware can be configured to determine which incoming requests it gets run for.  It can be only for a single URL (not typical), a whole group of URLs such as everything start with a particular path, or all URLs on the entire site.